# How to reconnect to a websocket when connection fails in python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, websocket

Hi I created async websocket client which I can receive and send messages asynchronously.

Here is the clint class that I use.

```
import websockets
import asyncio
from models import Heartbeat
from model_helper import ModelHelper
from json_helper import JSONHelper
from os.path import dirname, abspath
import logging
import time
waiting_time = 0.5

class WebSocketClient():

    def __init__(self, websocket_queue, configs):
        self.Heartbeat = Heartbeat().message
        self.websocket_queue = websocket_queue
        self.configs = configs

    def get_connection_string(self):
        server_url = self.configs.URL + ":" + str(self.configs.Port) + self.configs.Root
        return server_url


    async def connect(self):

        try:
            server_url = self.get_connection_string()
            self.connection = await websockets.client.connect(server_url)

            if self.connection.open:
                print("Connection stablished. Client correcly connected")
                # Send greeting
                await self.connection.send(self.Heartbeat)
                return self.connection

            else:
                print("Can not connect")

        except ConnectionRefusedError as err:
            print("Connection Error: {}".format(err))


    async def send_message_to_socket(self, connection):
        while True:
            message = self.websocket_queue.get_send_queue()
            try:
                if message is not None:
                    message_ = ModelHelper.to_outgoing_request_model(message)
                    await connection.send(message_)
                else:
                    await asyncio.sleep(waiting_time)
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed')
                self.connect()


    async def receive_message_from_socket(self, connection):
        while True:
            try:
                message = await connection.recv()
                obj = JSONHelper.toObject(message)
                print("Received object from websocket: {}".format(obj))


                #If a websocket entry  has SendMessage in its Action property
                #Consider it as an sms content to be sent.
                if(obj.Action == "SendMessage"):
                    self.websocket_queue.add_received_queue(obj)

            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed1')


    async def send_heartbeat_to_socket(self, connection):
        while True:            
            #print("Heartbeat loop\n")
            try:
                await connection.send(self.Heartbeat)
                await asyncio.sleep(3)
            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed2')
```

And this is the code where I listen for websocket messages:

```
def listen_websocket_routine(sms_queue, websocket_queue):
    while True:
        time.sleep(waiting_time)
        #Check Websocket queue for new messages
        message = websocket_queue.get_received_queue()

        # If Incoming websocket JSON has SendMessage string in its Action attribute transform it to request_model
        if message is not None and send_sms.Action == "SendMessage":
            # Transform it to  outgoing_sms_model
            reset = ModelHelper.to_outgoing_sms_model(message.Data)
            # Add To send_queue of sms
            sms_queue.add_send_queue(reset)
```

finally How I initiate them with asyncio and threading.

```
client = WebSocketClient(websocket_queue, configs)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
connection = loop.run_until_complete(client.connect())

task1 = asyncio.ensure_future(client.receive_message_from_socket(connection))
task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(client.send_heartbeat_to_socket(connection))
task3 = asyncio.ensure_future(client.send_message_to_socket(connection))


listen_websocket_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_websocket_routine, args=(sms_queue, websocket_queue))

listen_websocket_thread.start()

loop.run_forever()
```

So my question is, whenever connetion breaks, I need to re establish the connection. But I am not sure where should I do that. Should it be before everytime I try to send message or receive or should I do that in more general approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since update [10.0](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project/changelog.html#id4) you could do it with an async iterator, like this(example from the official [doc](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/client.html#opening-a-connection)):

```
async for websocket in websockets.connect(...):
    try:
        ...
    except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
        continue
```